# Cannot set the background color of "TD" using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table as under

```
<table >
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">EmpId</th><th scope="col">EmpName</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>ABC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td><td>DEF</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I want to set the background color of only the **"td"** elements of the table and not **"th"**. I have tried with

```
$("table").children("td").css('background-color', '#00ff00');

OR



$("table").children("tr").children("td").css('background-color', '#00ff00');
```

But with no result.

Please help as what mistake I am doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like following:

```
$("table tr").find("td").css('background-color', '#00ff00');
```

or

```
$("table td").css('background-color', '#00ff00');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/130/)**

According to @Matt Huggins's comment, you can do like following also:(but not necessary)

```
$("table tbody td").css('background-color', '#00ff00');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/ADuEU/)**

Comment: is there any difference if we do $("table td") ?

Comment: that works beautifully. But what was my mistake.Because "Td" is a child of "Tr". that why not mine worked?

Comment: Probably because when you create a TABLE, an implicit TBODY wraps your TRs.  So this probably would have worked (though is not recommended): `$("table").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").css('background-color', '#00ff00');`